# Is there a way in Django Admin, without custom HTML, to add a custom autocomplete_field that upon save provides a queryset to a model field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, widget

Currently, in one of my Django admin model views, I am able to individually select multiple available countries (Applicant countries) as is available in my database:

[image]

But this is very tiresome when actually I only really work with a handful of country groupings. But I do have a need to add or subtract the odd country without being required to manage and think of category names for each group of countries.

The idea I had was to use keywords (also serves other purposes in the application):

[image]

What I want to do is add a custom field via `admin.ModelAdmin` that is also an `autocomplete_field`, showing the keywords associated with countries in a dropdown. If an item on this dropdown is selected, it would return a queryset of countries with selected keyword to the model field (Applicant countries). Nothing else would need to be saved, don't need to keep track of which country associated keywords were used in the past. It is just a shortcut to bulk selecting many countries at once (so upon add/edit, the custom field would always appear empty).

I want as far as possible to do things the Django admin way, without touching custom HTML and things like that. If this is not possible, I will explore a solution that involves a [Django-Q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/) task.

Here is some code to explain the relationships:

models.py -> Keyword:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

models.py -> Country:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    """
    More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1
    """

    name = models.TextField()
    alpha_2_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    alpha_3_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    independent = models.BooleanField()
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
```

models.py -> FundingProgram

```
class FundingProgram(models.Model):
    # Unimportant fields redacted
    applicant_countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
```

admin.py -> FundingProgramAdmin

```
@admin.register(models.FundingProgram)
class FundingProgramAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, DynamicArrayMixin):
    autocomplete_fields = (
        "applicant_countries",
    )
    search_fields = (
        "applicant_countries__keywords__name",
    )

    # Here is where I think I should make a custom field,
    # that acts as a multiple choice (autocomplete) dropdown where
    # a function takes input and returns a queryset to applicant_countries field
```

Comment: I haven't worked much with admin forms, but with regular forms you could modify the queryset on a field within the `__init__` to add additional filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the use of [Django Autocomplete Light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

This is what I did (only included relevant additions here, read docs on how to install the library, etc).

## views.py (Todo: Make below codeblock more DRY)

```
from dal import autocomplete

from my_app import models


class KeywordsSelect(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return models.Keyword.objects.none()
        qs = models.Keyword.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            # Todo: Probably worth sorting the queryset for consistency
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs

    def get_result_value(self, result):
        return result.pk


class CountriesSelect(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return models.Country.objects.none()
        qs = models.Country.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            # Todo: Probably worth sorting the queryset for consistency
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs

    def get_result_value(self, result):
        return result.pk
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from my_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^keywords-select/$", views.KeywordsSelect.as_view(), name="keywords-select",),
    url(r"^countries-select/$", views.CountriesSelect.as_view(), name="countries-select",),
 ]
```

The above creates an endpoint which can be queried like: `http://localhost:8000/countries-select/?q=Austri`, returning an output such as:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "text": "Austria",
      "selected_text": "Austria"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
}
```

Now we can modify admin to include a modified form that will call this endpoint in an autoselect box. Note below that I need to explicitly list all of the fields and to get two fields to exist side by side, they need to be contained in their own tuple, `("applicant_countries", "bulk_add_countries_by_keyword",)` below.

## admin.py

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms

class FundingProgramForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Newly created field not retrieved from models.py
    bulk_add_countries_by_keyword = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Keyword.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url="keywords-select"),
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        # applicant_countries is a field from models.py which gets overridden here
        widgets = {
            "applicant_countries": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                url="countries-select"
            )
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        qs = self.cleaned_data["applicant_countries"].union(
            models.Country.objects.filter(
                keywords__in=self.cleaned_data["bulk_add_countries_by_keyword"]
            )
        )
        self.cleaned_data["applicant_countries"] = qs
        return super(FundingProgramForm, self).save(commit=commit)


@admin.register(models.FundingProgram)
class FundingProgramAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FundingProgramForm
    # Other fields hardcoded below, otherwise they won't appear in model form
    fields = (
        ("applicant_countries", "bulk_add_countries_by_keyword",),
    )
    # Warning: Remove the following from autocomplete_fields, as it is already overidden with a django autocomplete light widget
    #     autocomplete_fields = (
    #         "applicant_countries",
    #     )
```